# Android Flurry miss event logs and params

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I've integrated Flurry SDK into Android app. When we actively tested our application, console was full of event logs and every event had a list of params.

We prepared app to release: compiled test-candidate apk with obfuscation and gave them for final test. We began to receive very strange statistics in console: for some events the name is present, but logs are empty and parameters aren't present.

We supposed it's due to obfuscation, hundred times reviewed our Proguard configuration, next lines are present:

```
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
```

We created 4 test keys and compiled app with combination of different settings: obfuscated/non-obfuscated and log to logcat/not log. (We print out HashMap of params into log, I don't speak about flurry log to logcat). Obfuscated apks didn't show anything different from non-obfuscated: for some event the event name is present but logs and params are missing.

I noticed two differences between periods of "Everything was cool, everything was logged" and "Some events have only names":

1. First period was before Flurry server failure on 18.03.2013, second period was after it.
2. For the first period our testers actively used application, events were often invoked. For the second period our testers tried to invoke each event as rarely as possible (but at least 1 time).

Are any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sending across this query to Flurry Support. As discussed on the ticket, we need some more information from you. Looking forward to your mail.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)